# C++ Script to count number of pattern occurrence

Tags: c++

I have this code that counts the number of pattern occurrence in textfile.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    // std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
    // return 0;

    ifstream fin("my_data.txt"); //opening text file
    int count=0;
    char ch[20],c[20];

    cout<<"Enter a word to count:";
    gets(c);

    while(fin)
    {
        fin>>ch;
        if(strcmp(ch,c)==0)
            count++;
    } 

    cout<<"Occurrence="<<count<<"n";
    fin.close(); //closing file

    return 0;
}
```

**However, upon testing I got this error**

10  2   C:\Users\80977432\Documents\C++\Untitled1.cpp   [Error] 'ifstream' was not declared in this scope

Comment: Try `std::ifstream`.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ifstream` `cout` `strcmp` , etc all belongs to namespace `std`.

So use `std::ifstream`, `std::cout` , etc

Also use `#include <fstream>`  for file I/O operation

`#include<cstring>`  for `std::strcmp`

Comment: my another question, If I have another textfile to read, where should I put it , in what directory orpath?

Comment: @rickyProgrammer Wherever you want, you would have to provide correct path to `ifstream` to locate that file.

Comment: Thank you, by default sir, where is the path that ifstream is locating? if my file is in Dekstop, what could be the correct path?

Comment: @rickyProgrammer There are obvious other bugs in your program, I'd suggest to search those on StackOverflow, for instance how you should read strings, numbers etc from a file. Please don't keep updating your post. There are several posts related to these errors.